# Google Custom Search API 403 Daily Limit Exceeded

Tags: google-api, google-custom-search

I am getting the daily limit exceeded error message 403 when trying to access google custom search engine API. Based on the official documentation: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview I get 10k queries per day. And I am pretty certain that I have queried below 2k today. I have enabled billing and have entered credit card information (My account also has a ).

I have two questions:

1. Where can I see the number of queries for a particular API that I have performed for a selected day on Google Developer Console?
2. What can be the reason behind daily limit error?

I have seen other similar questions and I am posting this because none of them seem to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution:

On Google Developer Console, Navigate to:

`APIs & Auth --> APIs --> YourAPI --> Quotas`. Google by default enters a limit which might not be the maximum allowable limit. However, you can change that in this menu and your App will get the new limits.

Also, you can see the daily usage for a API here: `APIs & Auth --> APIs --> YourAPI --> Usage`

Comment: Looks like you need to enable 'billing account' to avail this service

Comment: @UVM thanks!  that was the HARDEST thing to figure out =)

Comment: "Google by default enters a limit which might not be the maximum allowable limit." - seems that not anymore: CSE limits are set to 100 and this is the maximum value.

Comment: @RafałSwacha 100 is the limit for free searches. 10K is the limit if you pay.